# Appinventor - Webview does not open app link

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am trying in App inventor WebView to open an app link in the app store.
The html link open the mobile version of playstore website, but this is not what i need.I need the link open the app in the Google Play Store app.

This html page is embedded in the WebView.
Then the example with whatsapp App

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp">Buy it now</a>
```

I tried also `market://` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **WebViewString** property of the webviewer component to pass the URL back to App Inventor. Then use the Activity Starter to open the app in Google Play.

[How does the property Webviewer.WebViewString work?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2webviewstring)
[How to launch Google Play from within your app](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2play)

Comment: thank you, it work perfect by passing back a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link to your products from an Android app, create an Intent that opens a URL. As you configure this intent, pass "com.android.vending" into Intent.setPackage() so that users see your app's details in the Google Play Store app instead of a chooser.

The following example directs users to viewing the app containing the package name com.example.android in Google Play:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android"));
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(intent);
```

It's for native android deleopment. You can do similar way like this:

```
Action:android.intent.action.VIEW
DataUri:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android
ActivityPackage:com.android.vending
```

Comment: This is not AppInventor but native code, that i don't use.

Comment: I think you didn't check the last portion of my answer.

Comment: I have only html & js loaded in the webview..You can't call action in this language man